# Java SE 6u28 not available within archives to download

Tags: java, java-6

Any idea why Java SE 6u28 is not available to download within [official archives](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)?
Found on guy who is currently on this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Skipped Version Number**
>
> Release Java SE 6u29 follows release Java SE
>   6u27. There is no publicly available Java SE 6u28 release. Oracle used
>   release version 6u28 for an internal build, which was not necessary
>   once the fixes delivered on Java SE 6u29 were released.

You can find out more information here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u29-relnotes-507960.html